# Why does wrapping a function with a lambda fix stack overflow?

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming, stack-overflow, y-combinator

If *expression* evaluates to a function of one argument, I would have thought that lambda x: (*expression*)(x) is identical to *expression* - but this is not actually the case. Consider the two following definitions of the Y combinator:

```
def Y1(F):
    left = lambda x: x(x)
    right = lambda x: F(x(x))
    return left(right)

def Y2(F):
    left = lambda x: x(x)
    right = lambda x: lambda y: (F(x(x)))(y)
    return left(right)
```

Y2 actually works as expected, but calling Y1 raises a stack overflow. Why is there this difference in behavior?

Comment: A function abstracts from an expression by generalizing it with an argument. Such an expression is only evaluated when the argument is provided, i.e. it is lazily evaluated. Adding a redundant lambda function has exactly this effect. This technique is called [eta abstraction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) and is used in strictly evaluated languages to introduce lazyness.

Answer (score 2):

No, `lambda x: (expression)(x)` is not identical to `expression`.

It is a function that *will* return the result of `expression` when called, unlike `expression` that returns its result right away.

What is that result? It is a function of one parameter. But it's not there quite yet. It needs to be constructed, calculated. And that's what `expression` is doing. It calculates that recursive function representing the "next" recursive call that *might need to be done* by the recursive function constructed by **Y** combinator.

`Y1` tries to find the value of `right` prematurely, too soon, too eagerly -- it tries to do this *before* returning the calculated recursive function. Which is thus never returned, because `Y1` always tries to calculate the next recursive function before returning the previous one so it can be called.

But `Y2` constructs the recursive function that *will* calculate the *next* recursive function when *it* will be needed; but not yet, not "now". It constructs it as the lambda function, which *delays* the actual calculation. The construction of a lambda function is a simple one-step process which completes quickly, and then the calculated recursive function is returned, so it can be used -- and only if/when *it* will determine that the *next* level of recursive call needs to be performed, it will call that lambda *at that point in time* to construct that next recursive function *at that point in time*, i.e. just before calling it.

Not way *way* in advance as the `Y1` is trying to do.